# Red5 installation help

Tags: red5

I have installed red5 client..But when i tried to start this nothing happens..When i see the log
Error log

2010-11-23 15:48:42,887 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] WARN  o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableRmiAdapter' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableRmiAdapter(boolean)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableRmiAdapter(java.lang.String)]
2010-11-23 15:48:42,887 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] WARN  o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableSsl' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableSsl(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableSsl(boolean)]
2010-11-23 15:48:42,887 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] WARN  o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableMinaMonitor' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(boolean)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(java.lang.String)]
2010-11-23 15:48:46,763 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] WARN  o.s.b.f.c.CustomEditorConfigurer - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [java.net.SocketAddress; offending editor instance: org.apache.mina.integration.beans.InetSocketAddressEditor@1e2670b

Comment: in youtube a girl has very good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "warnings" that you have posted have been resolved for quite some time now, I suggest that you try a newer build. Also these are warnings not errors, without seeing the rest of your console I would assume the server started as expected.